# SqlDataReader out of range exception.. cannot solve it

Tags: c#, sql-server

[image]

I have been trying to get it working for almost an hour now and cannot make any sense why it is not working. Please help!! This is my code

```
SqlDataReader rs = cmdGet.ExecuteReader();
rs.Read();
var id = Convert.ToInt32(rs["id"]);
var mt = rs["mt"].ToString();
```

The SQL statement is this:

```
  SELECT TOP 1 
      id = 0,
      mt = MT
  FROM 
      MyTable
  ORDER BY 
      2
```

I id = 0 and the code breaks at mt line. Throws:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException

What's wrong? I looked at a lot of posts but could not resolve it.

Comment: id = 0? Huh? What is that doing? Have you tried running that query in something like SSMS to see what you get?

Comment: if you run the query what do you will get?

Comment: What does your table actually look like? It difficult to discern exactly what you are trying to do in your current query.

Comment: which one if field in you table mt or MT?

Comment: MT is the table

Comment: How do I add a picture of my table? i don't even know how to edit my question on here, too confusign

Comment: use the [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/42169708/edit) button below your post. To include a picture, press the icon (with a mountain and a sun) in the menu just above the area where you enter your question

Comment: click edit, and then in edit box, pres ctrl+g, and then it will popup with a new window, click on sliver box and browse your image and then click add..

Comment: thanks!! those buttons are way too small to be noticed..

Comment: `mt` is string or int? and why `id` is 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the exception said that you have no field named `mt` so you need to change your query into this and it should work:

```
SELECT TOP 1 id, mt
FROM MyTable
 WHERE id = 0
ORDER BY 2
```

Comment: my pleasure to help you :)